# Moved Wordpress to other folder (Windows) WAMP = 403 Forbidden

Tags: permalinks, directory, permissions, apache

I am using a local install of Wordpress for offline development on a Windows 10 machine, with WAMP on the server side.

This morning I have moved the folder containing the wordpress from

```
c:\users\username\wordpress
```

to

```
c:\users\username\otherfolder\wordpress
```

and I have modified vhosts.conf accordingly from

```
  <VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "c:\users\username\wordpress"
    ServerName test
      <Directory "c:\users\username\wordpress">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
      </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>
```

to

```
  <VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "c:\users\username\otherfolder\wordpress"
    ServerName test
      <Directory "c:\users\username\otherfolder\wordpress">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
      </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>
```

However now when accessing the local site I am trapped in a 403 error "Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.". This error occurs both on front side or in the back side (wp-admin).

This is the content of .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Do I need to change something else in the db using phpmyadmin? Or some data in the permalinks needs tweaks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered the problem. Documentroot in apache has changed, so updating this has fixed the problem